# post-increment operator seems irrelevant

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand why its necessary to include the post-increment operator
in the try block following the variable reassignment in order to get the code to
compile (it doesn't seem to increment the value of the variable). Any insight would be appreciated.

```
class Test{
    public static int[ ] getArray() { return null; } 
public static void main( String[] args){
        int index = 1;
        try{
            getArray()[ index = 3]++; //the value of index is reassigned 
        }
        catch (Exception e){ } //catch isn't executed since no exception is thrown
        System.out.println(" index = " + index);
    }
}
```

Comment: "catch isn't executed" - [really?](http://ideone.com/l1Eos7)

Comment: Ah. Interesting. Still not sure why its doing what its doing. But my assumption was wrong. An Exception is indeed thrown. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to understand why its necessary ...

Well to a first order, the whole program is "unnecessary".  It doesn't do anything that is objectively useful.

You could also say it is "unnecessary" because with the program as written the post-increment wont be executed.  (Erm ... maybe I'm giving away too much here ... except that other Answers have already done that.)

But actually, I think that is the whole point.  This looks like an example / question to test your understanding of the semantics of Java expression evaluation and exceptions.  As such, the *purpose* of the post-increment is to be a *red herring*; i.e. to distract you from the real answer.  That is its necessity ...

> post-increment operator seems irrelevant

Yes.  With the code as written, it is irrelevant.  But if the code was more realistic, it wouldn't be irrelevant.

Comment: Yes. You're correct. Its a snippet from a practice exam. Was trying to understand the writers logic. But what your explanation makes sense. The point IS to trip me up. Thx.

Answer (score 4):

This code would just cause NullPointerException, since it's trying to access the null reference returned by `getArray()`.

If, on the other hand, the `getArray()` method would return a non-null array, this expression would set the `index` variable to 3 and then increment the value of the 4th element in the array (assuming the array has a least 4 elements - otherwise it would throw an exception) by one.

It would make more sense, though, to store the array returned by `getArray()` in a variable (in order to keep a reference to it). Otherwise, there is no point to manipulating this array, since you would have no way to access it at the end of the `getArray()[ index = 3]++;` statement.

Answer (score 2):

It seems clear that you aren't showing us what your code really does, let's fix `getArray()` to return an `int[]` (instead of `null`) -

```
public static int[] getArray() {
    return new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
}
```

Then let's call it, to get an array, then use your post-increment and finally display the array that started as `[1,2,3,4,5]` -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int index = 1;
    int[] arr = getArray();
    arr[index = 3]++;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    System.out.println(" index = " + index);
}
```

The output is

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 5]
 index = 3
```

Because the post-increment changed the value at index 3 (the 4th value, which was 4) to 5.

Answer (score 1):

Consider your standard fare `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < someValue; i++) { 
  // loop body 
}
```

This is useful as a shorthand notation for `i += 1`, or `i = i + 1`.

In your case, you are incrementing the value at `getArray()[ index = 3]`, not the `index` variable. I doubt this does what you want (considering it would be `null`).